# Spring - get class property value without using PropertyUtils(commons lib)

Tags: java, spring

I want to get a property value from a bean in my spring project. In my project I don't have Commons BeanUtils. Also I don’t want to include that lib.

I need an alternative to the code statement below, in spring.

```
 PropertyUtils.getProperty(entity, field)
```

Comment: Are you using autowiring, XML and/or properties files?

Comment: @Daniele I am using autowiring, i want to get value from simple bean class(Which not there in spring context). I need alternative of PropertyUtils.getProperty(entity, field) in spring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest equivalent to Commons BeanUtils that comes built into the JDK is `java.beans.Introspector`.  This can analyse the getter and setter methods on a class, and return an array of `PropertyDescriptor[]`.

Clearly this isn't as high-level - with this you need to hunt out the right property in that array.  At a minimum (with no exception handling):

```
public static Object getProperty(Object bean, String propertyName) {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass());
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = Arrays
            .stream(beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors())
            .filter(pd -> pd.getName().equals(propertyName)).findFirst()
            .get();
    return propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(bean);
}
```

If you have Spring in the mix though, `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils` helps with finding that `PropertyDescriptor`:

```
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = BeanUtils
            .getPropertyDescriptor(bean.getClass(), propertyName);
```

This will also be more efficient over time - behind the scenes Spring is using `CachedIntrospectionResults`.